# Errors deploying app on Google Cloud app Engine

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

This is my first time doing this, I have few hypothesis as to why I'm getting "access denied" and "Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds."

1. My app structure, it contains, html, css, js and php files. From the tutorials I saw every single file was php, I set the entry point of my app.yaml file to index.html when runtime is php83. Maybe that's a reason?
2. Something wrong with the google cloud? I don't think that's it because it all looks good and I successfully gcloud app deploy

I'm very confused, and it feels like I just wasted 8 hours on a Saturday trying to make my database accessible online. Any help would be appreciated

I tried removing all files except index.html, css files and app.yaml to see if the problem was the code and got
"Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds."

Comment: There isn't enough information in your post to help. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions. A good place to start debugging is to check your logs. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/logs and check the contents for your server error. That should probably help narrow down what the issue is

Comment: Can you share piece of element that help us to understand/reproduce your issue?